# Displaying only trendline (using Google Charts or other)

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, google-visualization

Here, I'm trying to diplay on chart (JQuery using Google Charts) one or various trendlines related to values I get from my DB (PHP).
I can create my charts, displaying something like 5 lines .Those are values for some dates and I foung how to display trenlines using dates.
My question is : I don't want the data lines, this is not my interest, I only want the trendlines but I can't seem to find a way...

I didn't put any code here but in the end code isn't needed, I'll provide it if a solution is suggested so it can be applied to that specific case.
Thank you for your help !

I tried to hide the lines, but when I remove all series, I have an error displayed, saying that there is not enough data to create a chart.
I also tried to put opacity to 0 but the displaying becose MORE than weird !

This is the data only display
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BRhWB.png)

This is the display with trendlines
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7oBuR.png)
As you can see, become hard to distinguish what is data, what is trendline, it became too heavy.

Trying to put opacity : 0 to all series
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WVTrE.png)
This doesn't make sense anymore...
Just so you know, after the

```
var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById(this_kpi + '__' + this_aggreg));
chart.draw(data, options);
```

I added :

```
view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
view.setColumns([
    1, 2, 3, 4, 5,
    {
         calc: function (data, row) {
                 var opacity  = 'opacity: 0;'
         },
         type: 'string',
         role: 'style'
     }
]);
chart.draw(view, options);
```

As a reminder I'd like to insist that the way doesn't really matters , what I try to do is display ONLY the trendlines for each serie. That and only that

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add a [mcve]

Comment: use 'transparent' as the color for each series. in the above opacity example, you're only setting opacity to zero on the last series. you would have to insert a calculated column after every series. which is how the style role works. but you don't need that, just set color to transparent in the options. --> `colors: ['transparent', 'transparent', 'transparent', 'transparent', 'transparent']` -- having the complete code that draws the chart is helpful to us in order to try out our solution before providing an answer.

Comment: It worked perfectly !
I just had to follow the same logic with the trendlines because they ended up transparent too :

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @WhiteHat !
It worked perfectly !
I just had to follow the same logic with the trendlines because they ended up transparent too :
here is the complete code for "option" to reach my goal

```js
var options = {
  trendlines: {
    0: {
      visibleInLegend: true,
      color:"blue",
    },
    1: {
      visibleInLegend: true,
      color:"red",
    },
    2: {
      visibleInLegend: true,
      color:"green",
    },
    3: {
      visibleInLegend: true,
      color:"orange",
    },
    4: {
      visibleInLegend: true,
      color:"purple",
    },
  },
  animation: {
    startup: true,   /* Need to add this for animations */
    duration: 1000,
    easing: 'out',
  },
  title: this_kpi + " - " + this_aggreg,
  smoothline: 'true',
  curveType: 2,
  legend: { position: 'bottom' },
  colors: ['transparent', 'transparent', 'transparent', 'transparent', 'transparent']
};
```